# Raspan: Execute Python Script from Java/Tomcat, tomcat8 user not acc

Tags: java, python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, tomcat8

Hi I try to execute python from a java/war file. Tomcat can access this file cause it generates it. As the pi or root user I can execute the script file generated without problem. But the tomcat8 process does not run the script file correct.

For some reason I cannot change to the tomcat8 user by su tomcat8 to try if the tomcat8 user can, which I do not understand.

I use this code

```
        public static void executePythonScript(String pathScriptFile) {

        try{

            File f = new File(pathScriptFile);
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath() +" exists:"+ f.exists());
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", pathScriptFile);
            Process p = pb.start();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String ret = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("value is : "+ret);
            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}


    }



        @RequestMapping(value="/api/togglegaragedoor")
    public  String toggleGarageDoor() {     
        try {
        String prg = "#!/usr/bin/env python\n\nimport automationhat\\n\nautomationhat.relay.one.on()";
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/pi/Pimoroni/automationhat/examples/relay_on.py"));
        out.write(prg);
        out.close();

        String prg2 = "#!/usr/bin/env python\n\nimport automationhat\\n\nautomationhat.relay.one.off()";;
        BufferedWriter out2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/pi/Pimoroni/automationhat/examples/relay_off.py"));
        out2.write(prg2);
        out2.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Api.executeCommand("which python");


        Api.executePythonScript("/home/pi/Pimoroni/automationhat/examples/relay_on.py");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Api.executePythonScript("/home/pi/Pimoroni/automationhat/examples/relay_off.py");
        return "toggled";
    }
```

I not getting any errors. The pi should trigger a relay that is not clicking. The value returned is null. The relay is clicking as pi user. The python exe is the same (which python.)

"/home/pi/Pimoroni/automationhat/examples/automationhat/**init**.py", lin                                                                                                                                                   e 354, in setup
    _ads1015 = ads1015(smbus.SMBus(1))
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

```
GPIO.setup(self.pin, GPIO.OUT, initial=0)
```

RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!

Comment: What are the errors or exceptions that you get? Update the question so that we could pinpoint what the issue might be

Comment: You can use sudo su tomcat8 to switch the user and execute the script under the tomcat8 user context

Comment: sudo su tomcat8 wont work, I type in password and I am still the pi user. I not getting any errors. The pi should trigger a relay that is not clicking. The value returned is null.

Comment: try using pb.redirectErrorStream(true); before pb.start to redirect the stderr to stdout to see if there are any errors printed.

Comment: thank you now i get this error from the lib:"/home/pi/Pimoroni/automationhat/examples/automationhat/init.py", lin e 354, in setup _ads1015 = ads1015(smbus.SMBus(1)) IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: thank you... this is it need to add the tomcat8 user to sudoers file with no password and execute python script with sudo...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170143/discussion-between-lasitha-petthawadu-and-user1786641).

Answer (score 0):

thank you... this is it need to add the tomcat8 user to sudoers file with no password and execute python script with sudo...